# How to prevent IAM user from seeing full list of lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ReadOnlyPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetAccountSettings",
                "lambda:GetEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:GetFunctionCodeSigningConfig",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConcurrency",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListTags",
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:abc-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have granted the above policy to the user.
But `lambda:ListFunctions` seems to only allow resource `*`.

Is there a way to make sure that only functions that start with a specific word are retrieved, or only functions with a specific tag?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS Lambda - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awslambda.html) page shows that `ListFunctions` does *not* take any Conditions.

So, it's an "all or nothing" call -- they either get a list of *all* functions, or they cannot view *any* functions.

But... you could write a Lambda function that calls `ListFunctions` and then only returns a subset of the results!